# Don't replace for-each by LINQ query

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.1

ReSharper wants to replace for-each by LINQ queries. I don't like that, and I don't want ReSharper even suggesting it.

How can I disable this?

I cannot find this in the ReSharper settings.

I don't want this `// ReSharper disable LoopCanBeConvertedToQuery` to be around each for-each.

Answer (score 1):

I have a newer version, ReSharper 9, but here it is under *ReSharper* > *Settings* > *Code Inspection* > *Inspection Severity*. I think it might be there in your version as well.

There is a long list of all things it can show improvements on. Somewhere in there is *Language Usage Opportunities* which has two settings about loops and LINQ.

[image: ReSharper Settings]

In ReSharper 9 there is also a possibility to search the settings above the treeview on the left or above the list in the *Inspection Severity* screen. Just type 'LINQ' there and it will show you the settings described above immediately.

Comment: You can also set the severity directly from the alt+enter menu.